# "... his life had to be like that" vs "... his life have to have been like like that" - what is difference?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the use of "have to have been" and "had to be". It's like the same thing comes out.

Comment: The second is incorrect. It should be "his life **has** to have been like that".

Comment: I've closed this question because without context, it's not possible to answer this. Is it about someone who was demanding about how their life was? Is it about someone whose life was fated to be a certain way? It is someone guessing what someone's life must have been like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a reason after "like that" to complete the two sentences, and the difference in meaning between them should become clear:

**"His life [???] to [???] like that *because*..."**

Here's the first version, with the simple past:

1. "His life **had to be** like that, because he never **brushed** his teeth."

And here's the second version, with the present perfect:

2. "His life **has to have been** like that, because otherwise he **wouldn't need** dentures."

The first version gets completed with a reason (the "because" clause) which is also in the simple past tense ("brushed"). It is also in the *indicative* mood, because it is a *certain* thing. You *know* he never brushed his teeth, and you're using that to make a confident assertion about the effect that habit had on his life *in the past*.

The second version gets completed with a reason in the present subjunctive ("wouldn't need"). The sense is of a deduction being made, not of a known fact.  You're speculating about the past (*what his life must have been like*) based on an observation in the present (*he needs dentures*).

**So, the difference between the two variants is this:**

*1.* is talking only about known events in the past;

*2.* looks at both past events and their present consequences, and makes an inference about the past from the present.